# Django language internationalisation - I cannot get translations to work

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm trying to figure out how to get different languages, based on user selection, to show in Django.  I don't know what I'm missing, so I wonder if someone can explain where I've gone wrong.

This is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="lang_test/index.html"))
)
```

Within **settings.py** I've added:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('el', _('Greek')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I've run

```
manage.py makemessages -fr
manage.py makemessages -el
```

and having added messages I've run

```
manage.py compilemessages
```

I've then got this simple template which I was expecting to see the 3 different languages showing because I've set the language.

```
{% load i18n %}

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        {{ LANGUAGE_CODE|language_name }}
        <h1>{% trans "Welcome to my website" %}</h1>

        {% with 'fr' as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {{ LANGUAGE_CODE|language_name }}
            <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
            <h1>{% trans "Welcome to my website" %}</h1>
        {% endwith %}

        {% with 'el' as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {{ LANGUAGE_CODE|language_name }}
            <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
            <h1>{% trans "Welcome to my website" %}</h1>
        {% endwith  %}

    </body>

</html>

The output is
English
Welcome to my website
French
Welcome to my website
Greek
Welcome to my website
```

Clearly, this isn't how to test if I've set it up properly.  How do I test I've got the translations working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates), you can use the `language` template tag:

```
{% language 'en' %}
     {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
     <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
     <h1>{% trans "Welcome to my website" %}</h1>
{% endlanguage %}

{% language 'el' %}
     {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
     <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
     <h1>{% trans "Welcome to my website" %}</h1>
{% endlanguage %}
```